# Can AWS ELB access logs be formatted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Can the default format of the access logs of Elastic Load Balancer in AWS can be changed and set to a custom format. If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the log format cannot be changed.

However, you can query the logs using Amazon Athena. This will make it easier to extract the information you seek.

See: [Querying Application Load Balancer Logs - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/application-load-balancer-logs.html)